# StackOverflowException in GetChildRows

Tags: c#

```
 DataRow[] arr;
 arr = (datasset.Tables["Director"].Rows[1]).GetChildRows("fk_FilmDir");
```

Visual Studio throws a `StackOverflowException` for the second row and I don't get why,it should return 2-3 datarows. What's wrong with my code?

LE:

```
public void showChildren()
        {

            int id = listBoxparent.SelectedIndex;

            list_film = new List<string>();
            DataRow[] arr;
            arr = (ds.Tables["Director"].Rows[id]).GetChildRows("fk_FilmDir");

            foreach (DataRow r in arr)
            {
                string s = "";
                s = r[0] + " " + r[1]+ " " +r[3];
                list_film.Add(s);

            }

            listBoxchildren.DataSource = list_film;
            listBoxchildren.Refresh();


            daf.Update(ds, "Film");
            ds.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

This is my function and now the exception occurs at Refresh()

Comment: appearently you're stuck in an infinite loop. probably a circular reference. can you post the whole code?

Comment: Can you describe your dataset?

Comment: @RezaRahmati my dataset contains 2 tabels, first one is  "Director" and the second one is  "Film". Between them is a one-to-many relationship

Comment: why dont write a separate sample app contains only the responsible code to regenerate your issue with some comments clarifying where exactly the exception thrown

Comment: Are you sure that GetChildRows doesn't call showChildren or something like that? Did you try executing the problematic line in a seperate context?